# How to edit a third-party package for Meteor

Tags: debugging, meteor, package

I have found and fixed a bug in a third-party Meteor package. When testing the fix, I ran into some unexpected difficulties, which I describe below.

What is the recommended method for testing a patched third-party package in Meteor?

---

On Mac, the command `meteor add username:package-name` copies files from Atmospherejs.com to the folder at `~/.meteor/packages/username_package-name/`. I located the original file in this folder and edited it.

The issue was simple. The original script included the lines...

```
options.userCallback = function (error) {
  if (error.error ...) {}
```

All I needed to do was to change this to:

```
options.userCallback = function (error) {
  if (error && error.error ...) {}
```

However, I had now added 9 characters to file. When Meteor compiled my app, it cut off the last 9 characters of the script, and this caused a runtime error. Presumably, Meteor stores the expected length of the file somewhere. As a hack, I removed more that 9 inessential whitespace characters from the file. Now Meteor complained that it could not read the entire file. So I added too much whitespace at the end of the file, and Meteor was happy to trim off the characters that it didn't want.

I was now able to check that my fix was valid, and post an issue for the package on its GitHub page, so that the original developer can release a fix.

This particular package was included as part of a different package, so it was installed as the result of a `meteor add otheruser:different-package-name` command.

What is the accepted method for overriding the files stored in the default package location, so that a patched version can be used instead, without Meteor getting persnickety about the exact number of bytes in the script file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spent too much time to prevent meteor update your change to the original again. The simplest way is

1. Fork the original project
2. Pull your forked repo into folder `packages` in your `meteor` project
3. Change anything you want on the forked
4. Include it to the meteor packages file (.meteor/packages). Remember to remove the old package by triggering `meteor remove <package-name>`
5. Run project

By default, meteor will look at the `packages` folder first for the external package, if it cannot found, then it will look up on `Atmosphere`.

By that time, just notify the original developer by the pull request from your repo.

Comment: "manually retrieve your changed repo as a package and include it in the meteor package file" <<< can you give me more precise details on how to "manually retrieve" it and where exactly it should go, to override the officially `meteor add`ed version?